# select items from story where story.uid equal to uid or story.uid equal to friend.uid or friend.fid and accepted

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How could I fetch a specific record only and if a condition is met?

I have the code as

```
"SELECT a.id, a.text, a.uid, a.time 
FROM story a INNER JOIN friends b 
         ON ((a.uid = '" . $uid . "') OR 
             (b.uid = '" . $uid . "' AND accepted='1')  OR 
             (b.fid = '" . $uid . "' AND accepted='1')) 
ORDER BY a.time DESC 
LIMIT 3";
```

It works fine except that when the `friends` table is empty, it will not show the `story` records.

**what i want to achieve is**

- if the *uid* in table **story** is equal to *logged in uid* (user), then show the *text* from table **story** (meaning it is his own story)
- if the *uid* in table **story** is equal to *uid* in table **friends** and its friendship is *accepted* **OR** if the *uid* in table **story** is equal to *fid* in table **friends** and its friendship is *accepted* then show the *text* in table **story** (meaning the story is from a friend and its shown only if friendship is accepted)
- if *there is no friendships* at all, just show *own stories* from table **story** and omit others

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but if your question is in regards to the way inner joins work, you can use an outer join when you still want to return a row even when the table you are joining to might not have a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using proper join format. It should be as :

```
    SELECT field_name 
    FROM table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.some_id 
    WHERE..
```

You can check the basics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

In your case you should write query as following:

```
    "SELECT a.id, a.text, a.uid, a.time 
    FROM story a INNER JOIN friends b 
    ON a.id = b.some_id WHERE ((a.uid = '" . $uid . "') OR
    (b.uid = '" . $uid . "' AND accepted='1')  OR 
    (b.fid = '" . $uid . "' AND accepted='1')) 
    ORDER BY a.time DESC 
    LIMIT 3";
```

I think it will help.

Comment: figured out, removing the **a = b.some_id** and making it **LEFT JOIN** will do the trick. thanks